# How to fix error "Can't play this video"? (m3u8) file

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, m3u8

I'm working with ExoPlayer and m3u8 file. Every time when I run my app it says that

> Can't play this video

Probably everything should be right but I don't know why it says like that

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">


<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

VideoView videoView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();

    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);



    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://mos.rusiptv.net:8080/live/@celalsonat/784512/94815.m3u8"));
    videoView.start();

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is exoplayer code?

Comment: I deleted because it didn't work

Comment: I did it with normal media player

Comment: check your link `Stream` in `VLC player`

Comment: I already did this and it works very well

Answer (score 0):

there are many reasons for that..

1.If your video is corrupted then videoplayer shows that dialog..

2.if your video is completed and not corrupted then try this,

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        videoView.start();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

3.Exoplayer is the best alternative of videoview in android studio.

just implement this dependancy, in several places

```
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   jcenter()
}


dependencies {
...
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.0'
```

}

and Bam you done...
please check this for more information,

```
 https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer
```

Hope this will help you..!!!

Comment: Actually I have ExoPlayer dependency. But I don't know how to work with that. Can you write simple code?

Comment: I have created Project on github please refer this:-  
    https://github.com/kashyap0001/SimpleExoplayer.git    Watchvideo class contains Your answer...Hope this will Work for you...Donot forget to Voteup the answer.!!!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I wrote code from watchvideo.java but there's nothing

Comment: have you add network configuration in manifest and xml like i have done in manifest ..? also you have to create xml file in res directory.

Answer (score 0):

To play .m3u8 file use below code while initializing Exoplayer:-

```
BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);

TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

videoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context,trackSelector);

Handler mHandler = new Handler();

String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(context, "APPLICATION_NAME");

DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(
                userAgent, null,
                DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
                1800000,
                true);

HlsMediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource(Uri.parse(mediaUrl),dataSourceFactory, 1800000,mHandler, null);

if (mediaUrl != null) {
    videoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
    videoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
}
```

Comment: `DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(
                userAgent, null,
                DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
                1800000,
                true);`

Comment: And is it 2.11.3 exoplayer?

Comment: It has error on trackSelector(it says in ExoPlayer can't be applied to 'com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelector)

Comment: Then Adnroid Studio underlines HlsMediaSource red. It says "'HlsMediaSource(android.net.Uri, com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsDataSourceFactory, com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsExtractorFactory, com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.CompositeSequenceableLoaderFactory, com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DrmSessionManager<?>, com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.LoadErrorHandlingPolicy, com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistTracker, ...)' has private access in 'com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaSource'